# How can I make a block visible only for admin and teachers in Moodle?

Tags: block, moodle

I create and added a `block` in **Moodle** under a course. I want to make the `block` `only visible for teachers and admin`. How can I do this?

When students login to the site they should have no access(not visible) for them.

Please help me...

I am using **Moodle 2.9.1**

Comment: I suggest you ask this under SuperUser...

Comment: this question explains how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644417/how-to-make-a-block-visible-only-for-admin-and-teacher-in-moodle

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to *Hidden* Teachers and admin can still see it, but students cannot.