# How to make a block visible only for admin and teacher in moodle?

Tags: hide, block, moodle

I think there are more than one way to *make block invisible for students*.

> **1.**
>
> `Hide the block`
>
> **2.**
>
> `Assign role to block and set permission to block`

But these are done by admin by change the settings. I need a way by code. How can I write the code to make the block invisible for student.

For `activity I can make invisible the activity` by changing *db/access.php*

```
 'mod/questionbank:view' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
        'legacy' => array(
            //'guest' => CAP_ALLOW,
            //'student' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'admin' => CAP_ALLOW
        )
    ),
```

Like this **how can I make the block invisible for student by code.**

**EDIT**

according to **Davosmith's** answer.

I put inside `get_content` function

```
if (!has_capability('blocks/blockname:view')) {
        return null;
        }
```

in **blocks/blockname/block_blockname.php**

and in my **blocks/blockname/db/access.php** contain:

```
'blocks/blockname:view' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_BLOCK,
        'legacy' => array(
            //'guest' => CAP_ALLOW,
            //'student' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
           // 'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
        )
    ),
```

But it results in error page saying

> Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: PHP catchable
> fatal error

Answer (score 1):

For any block, if get_contents returns null (and editing is off), the block will not be displayed.

So, put the following in the get_content function of your block (but put in a real capability that you define in db/access.php):

```
if (!has_capability('block/myblock:somecapability', $this->context)) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - missed out the 'context' part of the function call. Please make sure debugging is on when doing any development work, as that gives much more helpful error messages - https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging